# Change width of dropdown according to screen resolution

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am trying to use a dropdown menu in react application. Everything seems to works fine, but one thing is bugging me when I try to try to change browser resolution from console.

```js
// index.js:
<select
    id="project_type"
    name="project_type"
    className="dropdown_menu"}
>
    <option value="Yes">
        Yes
    </option>
    <option value="No">
        No
    </option>
</select>
```

css file:

```css
.dropdown_menu {
    position: absolute;
    width: 590px;
    height: 48px;
    background: rgba(0, 50, 160, 0.1);
    margin-top: 270px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid rgba(46, 81, 158, 0.6);
    padding-left: 23.33px;
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

This happens when I try to change resolution:

[image]

How can I make the dropdown menu of equal width of its dropdown option instead of overflowing when changing resolutions.

Note: I have used 'width: inherit' but it doesn't work.

Comment: if my answer do what you you want make sure to approve to help future viewers get the solution quickly

Answer (score 1):

Just use `content-box`

```css
input,
select {
  -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

```html
<select id="project_type" name="project_type" className="dropdown_menu" }>
  <option value="Yes">
    Yes
  </option>
  <option value="No">
    No
  </option>
</select>
```